# How can I get fileversion information from a ETL file

Tags: trace, etw, etw-eventsource

With the [Microsoft TraceEvent Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent) it is possible to parse ETL files which are generated by [xperf, WPR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh162945.aspx) or [PerfView](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567).

I found out that the Event ImageIDFileVersion in TracEvent shows me the file version and the Event ImageGroup shows me the file paths of files. Now I need to map both events together and need a way to make sure both events point to the same file in the ETL trace file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important information come from the `ImageGroup` and `ImageIDFileVersion` events, so assign methods to the events:

```
using (_source = new ETWTraceEventSource(dataFileName))
{
     var kernelParser = new KernelTraceEventParser(_source);

     _source.Kernel.ImageGroup += KernelOnImageGroup;

     var symbolParser = new SymbolTraceEventParser(_source);      

     symbolParser.ImageIDFileVersion += SymbolParserOnImageIdFileVersion;

     // go into a loop processing events can calling the callbacks.  This will return when the all the events
     // In the file are processed, or the StopProcessing() call is made.
     _source.Process();
}
```

Basically the FileVersionTraceData event comes before the corresponding Image*event, and has the same timestamp. So the **Timestamp is used as the correlator**.

When the `ImageIDFileVersion` events occurs, you have to clone the current data into an other FileVersionTraceData object to store it for later use:

```
void SymbolParserOnImageIdFileVersion(FileVersionTraceData data)
{
     lastFileVersionData = (FileVersionTraceData)data.Clone();   
}
```

After this the second Event `ImageGroup` is hit. Here you must compare the timestamp (`TimeStampRelativeMSec`) with the stored data and if the timestamp matches both events point to the same file.

```
void KernelOnImageGroup(ImageLoadTraceData imageLoadTraceData)
{
     var fileName = imageLoadTraceData.FileName;
     {
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
          {
                if (lastFileVersionData != null && lastFileVersionData.TimeStampRelativeMSec == imageLoadTraceData.TimeStampRelativeMSec)
                {
                     var fileVersion = lastFileVersionData.FileVersion;
                     var origFileName = lastFileVersionData.OrigFileName;
                     Console.WriteLine("found File {0} with File Version {1}", origFileName, fileVersion);
                }
          }
      }
 }
```

Now you have the fileversion parsed from an ETL file. The important point is that the Timestamp is used as the correlator to find the correct data. This took me a while and the help of [Vance Morrison](http://blogs.msdn.com/3800/ProfileUrlRedirect.ashx) to figure out that Timestamp is used as the correlator and how to find the file version.